# Tab Item header styling inheritance

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm sure there is something simple I'm overlooking but for life of me haven't been able to figure it out. I have just started using MahApps Mmetro UI which has applied a style to all of my tabs. However on some tabs I needed the ability to do some string formatting so the headers are declared like this:

```
<TabItem Content="{Binding TaskList}">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count, StringFormat=Tasks (\{0\})}" />
     </TabItem.Header>
 </TabItem>
```

Tab Items with headers defined like this do not inherit the Metro UI Styling. Is there a way to apply the styling to all headers?

Comment: `<TabItem Header="{Binding Count, StringFormat=Tasks (\{0\})}"/>`

Comment: @Chris W. I've tried that but it doesn't work. It only displays the count but not the string "Tasks".

Comment: Oh right, close it `StringFormat='Tasks (\{0\})'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `BindingBase.StringFormat` is only used when the target property is of type `string`, but `TabItem.Header` is of type `object`, so binding it directly with `StringFormat` specified fails to give the expected result. Luckily, you can use the `TabItem.HeaderStringFormat` property to format the header text while maintaining the original style:

```
<TabItem Header="{Binding Count}" HeaderStringFormat="Tasks ({0})" (...) />
```

Mind though that `HeaderStringFormat` is only used when the value of `Header` is displayed as text (it is ignored when `Header` contains a control etc.).